# The access token is from the wrong issuer 'https://sts.windows.net'

Tags: azure, electron, azure-resource-manager

I am using  'azure-arm-resource' for get all resources in azure for my node js project.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-arm-resource

But using this I get some error,

```
 msRestAzure.interactiveLogin().then(credentials => {
  const azureResources = new resourceManagement.ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscriptionId);

  azureResources.resources
    .list()
    .then(res => {
      if (filter) {
        return res.filter(r => r.kind === filter);
      } else {
        return res;
      }
    })
    .then(d => {
      console.log('Done Resources');
    });
});
console.log('Pulling...');
 }
```

Error,

```
 Uncaught (in promise) Error: The access token is from the wrong issuer 
'https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx/'.
 It must match the tenant 'https://sts.windows.net/xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx- 
 c3xxx4xxffd57xx7/' 
 associated with this subscription. Please use the authority (URL) 
 'https://login.windows.net/xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx' to get the token. 
  Note, if the subscription is transferred to another tenant there is no 
 impact to the services, but information about new tenant could take time to 
  propagate (up to an hour). If you just transferred your subscription and  
  this error message, please try back later.
```

Device Token Credentials undefined in azure interactive login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you login on the portal ,when using an org id something@yourcompany-name.com , it will work, but when use a live id something@gmail.com, we need to pass TenantId.

Primary purpose is to make the login experience simple for the user. Hence we start with minimal required parameters. For interactiveLogin(), I thought it was zero. But that is incorrect. TenantId or domain must be provided when using liveID.

Comment: Thanks! I was using `AzureCliCredential(tenant_id="xxx")` without the `tenant_id`. Hence its was giving the this error.

Answer (score 0):

It means the subscription is not part of the tenant the account you logged in with is on.

Make sure the account you logged in with has access to the subscription used.

Comment: I tried const ArmResource = require('azure-arm-resource');

const subClient = new ArmResource.SubscriptionClient(credentials);
subClient.subscriptions.list().then(data => {
  console.log(data);
});   It's return empty. But I have one subscription in my portal.